# Angular Directive is applied to all elements instead of one

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 9 in a project and I used exactly the same directives in a Angular 8 project without problems.

I use for example a directive to block spacebar in input fields. This directive should be assigned to every input field manually that should use it. But instead of how it should work you assign it on one single input field and it works on all input fields and that is bad for e.g. a name field.

The directive:

```js
 @Directive({
   selector: "[blockKeyDownSpace]",
 })
 export class BlockKeyDownSpaceDirective {
   @HostListener("window:keydown", ["$event"]) blockSpace(
     evt: KeyboardEvent
   ): void {
     if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
       evt.preventDefault();
     } else if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 32) {
       evt.preventDefault();
     }
   }
 }
```

The html (shortened as good as possible):

```html
 <div @fadeAnimation class="col">
   <h1 class="header">
     {{ 'CHANGE_PASSWORD.HEADER' | translate }}</h1>
   <hr>
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
     <form class="change-form" [formGroup]="changeForm" (submit)="sendRequest(changeForm)">
 
       <mat-form-field class="form-field-full-width">
         <input matInput [maxlength]="globals.maxPasswordLength" required
           [type]="globals.hidePassword ? 'password' : 'text'" (capsLock)="capslockOn=$event"
           #password formControlName="password" />
         <button tabindex="-1" type="button" mat-icon-button matSuffix
           (click)="globals.hidePassword = !globals.hidePassword" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
           [attr.aria-pressed]="globals.hidePassword">
           <mat-icon>{{globals.hidePassword ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
         </button>
       </mat-form-field>
 
       <mat-form-field class="form-field-full-width">
         <input matInput [maxlength]="globals.maxPasswordLength" blockKeyDownSpace required
           name="passwordConfirmation"
           (capsLock)="capslockOn=$event" formControlName="passwordConfirmation" blockCopyPaste
           [type]="globals.hidePasswordConf ? 'password' : 'text'" />
         <button tabindex="-1" type="button" mat-icon-button matSuffix
           (click)="globals.hidePasswordConf = !globals.hidePasswordConf" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
           [attr.aria-pressed]="globals.hidePasswordConf">
           <mat-icon>{{globals.hidePasswordConf ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
         </button>
       </mat-form-field>
 
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I insert the directive in the `declarations` section in `app.module.ts`

And somehow the blockCopyPaste directive does not even work. I don't know what is bad in my setup. It's very strange behaviour.

Comment: Doubt this ever worked correctly..? You shouldn’t be using window:keydown but only ‘keydown’, otherwise only one of these directives on a page will apply it to all inputs (which is your issue)..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this type of directive, but why not just create an `<app-input>` component to handle all of these input fields?

and then pass in blockKeyDownSpace like this:

```
<app-input name="passwordConfirmation" [blockKeyDownSpace]="true"></app-input>
```

to me, seems more straight forward.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I mean it worked in another project. I just don't get what I could have forget this time that causes this behavior.

Comment: yeah not sure. it just seems angular has gotten away from directives, in favor of components, so I'm not surprised things aren't working properly.